# Select2 tags set value by function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I've a select2 where i need to create tags only if I got permission. I need to check permission by ajax by user-id.

Now setting is `tags: true` and i can ALWAYS create new tags. (ok)
If a set `tags: false` i can't create new tags. (ok)

I tried using tags: `function() { return false; }` but seem tags can be created anyway. (bad)

My goal is to have something like this:

```
tags: function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    dataType:"json",
    url: "ajax/check_permissione.php",
    data: { 'user-id': 1 },
    success: function(data, status) {
        if ( data.PermissionOK == 1 ) {
            return true;            
        }

        return false;       
    }
  });
}
```

But I don't know at this point if tags can accept value from a function?

My script:

```
$("#test").select2({
      tags: true, //  <- if true create new tags, else only select available
      createTag: function (params) {
        return {
          id: params.term,
          text: params.term,
          newOption: true
        }
      },
      templateResult: function (data) {
        var $result = $("<span></span>");
        $result.text(data.text);
        if (data.newOption) {
          $result.append(" <em>(new option)</em>");
        }

        return $result;
      }
}).on('select2:select', function (e) {

  //others operations

});
```

Comment: does your ajax work?

Comment: Yes, but i've tried also tried simple tags: function() { return false; } to try and doesn't work function()

Comment: I think you'll have to re-initialize select2 depending on the response of your ajax.

Comment: Aside from the issue you need to remove `async: false`. It's deprecated, as well as being terrible practice, and support for it will be removed soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `tags: true` into `tags: permission` where `permission` contains the value that indicates whether an user id has permission or not. If you check permission through ajax, you can store the result into the variable. Here is the illustration.

```
var permission = true;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    dataType:"json",
    url: "ajax/check_permissione.php",
    data: { 'user-id': 1 },
    success: function(data, status) {
        if ( data.PermissionOK == 1 ) {
            permission = true;
        } else {
            permission = false;
        }
    }
});
```

If you use ajax, execute this code first before using `select2`

Answer (score 1):

For your information.
You can implement this way if you want to avoid using 'async: false'.(using jQuery promise)

```
var permission = true;
var result =
    $.post({
        dataType:"json",
        url: "ajax/check_permissione.php",
        data: { 'user-id': 1 }
    }).done(function(data, status) {
        if ( data.PermissionOK == 1 ) {
            permission = true;
        } else {
            permission = false;
        }
    });

// called when ajax process done.
result.promise().done(function() {
    // $("#test").select2({ ~
});
```